useLocation Hook Error: "useLocation() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component" in React Application
I'm developing a React application and I'm encountering an error when using the useLocation hook from the react-router-dom library. The error message I receive is:

Error: useLocation() may be used only in the context of a 
component.

Here is the relevant part of my App.js file:
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

// Components
import Navigation from './components/Navigation'
import Section from './components/Section'
import Product from './components/Product'
import Login from './components/Login'

// ABIs
import Dappazon from './abis/Dappazon.json'

// Config
import config from './config.json'

const ethers = require('ethers')

function App() {
  const [provider, setProvider] = useState(null)
  const [dappazon, setDappazon] = useState(null)

  const [account, setAccount] = useState(null)

  const [electronics, setElectronics] = useState(null)
  const [clothing, setClothing] = useState(null)
  const [toys, setToys] = useState(null)

  const [item, setItem] = useState(null)
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false)

  const location = useLocation()

  const togglePop = (item) => {
    setItem(item)
    toggle ? setToggle(false) : setToggle(true)
  }

  const loadBlockchainData = async () => {
    const provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(window.ethereum)
    setProvider(provider)
    const network = await provider.getNetwork()

    const dappazon = new ethers.Contract(config[network.chainId].dappazon.address, Dappazon, provider)
    setDappazon(dappazon)

    const items = []

    for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
      const item = await dappazon.items(i + 1)
      items.push(item)
    }

    const electronics = items.filter((item) => item.category === 'electronics')
    const clothing = items.filter((item) => item.category === 'clothing')
    const toys = items.filter((item) => item.category === 'toys')

    setElectronics(electronics)
    setClothing(clothing)
    setToys(toys)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    loadBlockchainData()
  }, [])

  const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
      path: "/login",
      element: <><Navigation account={account} setAccount={setAccount} /><Login /></>
    },
    {
      path: "/",
      element: <><Navigation account={account} setAccount={setAccount} /></>
    },
    {
      path: "/Clothing&Jewelry",
      element: <><Navigation account={account} setAccount={setAccount} /><Section title={"Clothing & Jewelry"} items={clothing} togglePop={togglePop} /></>
    },
    {
      path: "/Electronics&Gadgets",
      element: <><Navigation account={account} setAccount={setAccount} /><Section title={"Electronics & Gadgets"} items={electronics} togglePop={togglePop} /></>
    },
    {
      path: "/Toys&Gaming",
      element: <><Navigation account={account} setAccount={setAccount} /><Section title={"Toys & Gaming"} items={toys} togglePop={togglePop} /></>
    },
  ])

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {/* <Navigation account={account} setAccount={setAccount} /> */}
        <RouterProvider router={router} />

        {electronics && clothing && toys && location.pathname === '/' && (
          <>
            <h2>Dappazon Best Sellers</h2>
            <Section title={"Clothing & Jewelry"} items={clothing} togglePop={togglePop} />
            <Section title={"Electronics & Gadgets"} items={electronics} togglePop={togglePop} />
            <Section title={"Toys & Gaming"} items={toys} togglePop={togglePop} />
          </>
        )}

        {toggle && (
          <Product item={item} provider={provider} account={account} dappazon={dappazon} togglePop={togglePop} />
        )}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;

I have already ensured that RouterProvider wraps the component that uses useLocation, but the error persists. The useLocation hook is being used within the App component which is wrapped inside the RouterProvider as shown above.
What could be causing this issue and how can I resolve it?

Maybe it's because you are using useLocation() outside the 'Router' component. I think the useLocation hook might be causing the issue because it's been used directly inside the App component.
I would create a component that will use the useLocation hook and then include this component within my RouterProvider routes if I were you

You have it the other way around, actually, where App is rendering the router and so it can't use anything that depends on the routing context. Either promote the router higher in the ReactTree, or create a root layout component that can use the useLocation hook.

Also, FWIW you will want to create the router outside the ReactTree so it's not re-creted each time the parent component rerenders for any reason so your routed components don't get re-mounted.
